# Fortran OpenMP private variables in subroutines

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

First of all: This problem was adressed in other questions like [how can i keep variables private in subroutines which are called in a parallel section of openmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170994/how-can-i-keep-variables-private-in-subroutines-which-are-called-in-a-parallel-s) and [Are local variables in procedures automatically private when using OpenMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24344608/are-local-variables-in-procedures-automatically-private-when-using-openmp), but my problem remains as follows.

I call a subroutine from inside an OpenMP parallel region and want the local variables be private for every thread, so that changes to local variables in one thread will not affect the other threads. However, I can't make it work in this example:

```
program omp_private
use omp_lib
implicit none

call test() !initalize temp = 0

!$omp parallel
call test()
!$omp end parallel


contains

subroutine test()
    integer :: temp = 0
    if (omp_get_thread_num()==1)    temp = 1
    if (omp_get_thread_num()==0)    write(*,*) "In thread ",omp_get_thread_num()," temp is ",temp
end subroutine test

end program omp_private
```

My output looks usually like this (depending on thread speed)

```
 In thread            0  temp is            0
 In thread            0  temp is            1
```

Adding `recursive` nor `save` changed anything. I cannot explicitly declare `temp` as private since `temp` is not defined outside the subroutine.
How could I make it work?

Comment: You say adding `save` (presumably to the declaration of `temp`) doesn't change anything, but it wouldn't: because you've explicitly initialized `temp` (the line `integer :: temp = 0`) it already has the `save` attribute.

Comment: Changing it to `integer :: temp` did indeed work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will close this as a duplicate and make this aspect more explicit in my answer because no-one answered this question.